# best approach for ROS2 creating a webfrontend

Tags: ros, ros2, web

[image: Rosanswers logo]

searching for ros2 and web brought back many manuals mentioning ros(1 ?) and web tools or rosbridge.

what would be the best approach creating a website with access to a ros2 middleware ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/314562/best-approach-for-ros2-creating-a-webfrontend/) by [vKuehn](https://answers.ros.org/users/17921/vkuehn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 116 on 2019-02-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Depending on how the web frontend is designed it might not even be tight to a specific ROS version. E.g. when using the [Robot Web Tools](http://robotwebtools.org/) your client side code only talks to a websocket.

A few of these server-side packages have already been ported to ROS 2. The last repository is currently in the process of being ported: https://github.com/ros2/rosbridge_suite/issues/1 Once that work is complete you should be able to use a webfrontend developed for ROS 1 in the same way for ROS 2.

One example of such a webfrontend is an RViz-like interface: https://github.com/osrf/rvizweb

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2019-02-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vKuehn](https://answers.ros.org/users/17921/vkuehn/) on 2019-02-04**:
thanks for that ! will be watching the releases there The new server side implementation looks like a pure python based one. the old one requiered nodejs so that is probably a good change